# Is it possible to automate creation of .pkpass files for AppleWallet and AndroidWallet for multiple users?

Tags: algorithm, mobile, wallet, pkpass

Depending on the fact that we have all the need data for the users to create the .pkpass files, the thing that misses is:

.cer files (certification, converted to .pem files and private.key needed)

For a bunch of users it is needed to automate the .pkpass file creation, so as everyone can with a click  receive the card on his wallet. But, how to provide the multiple .certification for all these people?Is there some authentication needed from each User? For example, we can receive the .cer file from Apple ID website.

P.S.:
Please, comment on how to fill in details about the question.